# Configure Code information Indicator in VS 2013 Premium with Update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How to Configure Code information Indicator in VS 2013 Premium with Update 4.

I can't see option for 'Show Reference' in VS 2013 Premium.

Please can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2013-oct-17-vs.aspx)

> CodeLens (Code Information Indicators) in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 uses information from both your project metadata and Team Foundation Server 2013 to place decorators on each of the methods in your code that show information such as what changesets led to the creation or recent change, who was the last person to work on the code, what unit tests cover the method (including the latest pass/fail state), and what code references exist. You can also quickly jump into that data, such as an associated changeset or referenced code file with just a click.

This function available only in Ultimate edition